# Windows batch script: use variable in diff command not working

Tags: batch-file, diff, gnu

I'm fairly new to batch scripting.  My script is only simple.
I've got the code so far to set 2 variable's of 2 filenames that are dynamic (may be different every time the script is run).

Now I want to use those variables in a "diff" command.

It may be relevant that I'm using GNU Diffutils

Script at the moment:

```
:Variables
SET FolderPath=H:\Marketing\Website\DB Files\CSV Outputs

@echo on
echo Upload Item Master diff to FTP
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%FolderPath%\*.csv" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
FOR /F "delims=|" %%J IN ('DIR "%FolderPath%\*.csv" /B /O:-D') DO SET OldestFile=%%J

echo Newest file %NewestFile%
echo Oldest file %OldestFile%

diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='%L' %OldestFile% %NewestFile% >%FolderPath%\DiffOut\IM-diff.csv
```

The output at the moment is:

```
    .....    
    H:\>echo Newest file DB Item Master table 17-03-17.csv
    Newest file DB Item Master table 17-03-17.csv

    H:\>echo Oldest file DB Item Master table 28-02-17.csv
    Oldest file DB Item Master table 28-02-17.csv

    H:\>diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='OldestFileNewestFileFolderPath\DiffOut\IM-diff.csv
    diff: missing operand after `--new-line-format='OldestFileNewestFileFolderPath\DiffOut\IM-diff.csv'
    diff: Try `diff --help' for more information.
```

I need the script to be able to put the variable file name in the command, so:

```
H:\>diff --unchanged-line-format= --old-line-format= --new-line-format='"DB Item Master table 28-02-17.csv" "DB Item Master table 17-03-17.csv" "H:\Marketing\Website\DB Files\CSV Outputs\DiffOut\IM-diff.csv"
```

Comment: Probably need to double the percent symbol on the new line format.  Remember that percent symbols have special meaning.  So it is seeing `%L' %` as the variable name to expand.  So change `%L`  to `%%L`

Comment: That is by design.  The 1> means it is redirecting standard output to the file.  You can't make cmd.exe not expand the > to 1>.

Comment: Delete your comment with the code and edit your question. Hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Thanks, adding the extra % made it work!

Many thanks to Squashman

(BTW the > output problem was to do with something else - I sorted that OK)